# Load dynamic html content from asset folder file in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, assets

In my angular application I want to load some html content from a file located in my assets folder.

The path of the folder will be dynamic based on the value selected by the user,

**For example**:

If the user selects locale as INDIA, the html has to be loaded from the India folder inside assets.

There is a chance that locale file is not available in assets folder, so then it should default back to English/USA folder.

I have tried with http request.

```
downloadFile(url: string, contentType: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, {
      responseType: 'text',
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Content-Type': contentType,
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKeys.AUTH_CODE)
        })
    })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<any>(url)));
  }
```

Now the problem is on the server when the request goes if the assets is not there its still return 200 and the index.html in response.

In local it return a 404.So the fallback works.

How can I fix this .Why on the server it returns 200?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you want to load the same content in different languages, you use something like i18n with the Angular TranslateModule.

With that you can use the Browser Language Setting, and automatically load your texts in the right language.

For your question, it would make sense that you also upload you background load, so that we can find your mistake.